# How to output a std::map to a binary file?

Tags: c++, file, stl, dictionary, binary

How can I output a `std::map` to a binary file?

The map declaration looks like this.

```
map<string, Account *> accounts;

ofstream os(outFileName.c_str());
os.write(  );
```

I need to know what to put into the `write()` function to have it work the way I want. Do I need to output the class `Account` one-by-one or am I safe to just output it as a `map`?

Comment: @Jeff: You don't get to just put random abbreviations in code blocks and call it an edit.

Comment: I'm not sure what your intention with `Account*` is. If you want this to be a pointer, why not use C++'s smart pointers? Or if you intended for this to be an array, then `std::vector` should do the trick.

Comment: @chrisaycock: The question is not tagged c++11, nor is there any mention of it, so it's safe to assume that smart pointers are not available.  It's almost certainly just a standard pointer to a single object.

Comment: @Wug C++03 has `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: @chrisaycock: You would not want to have an auto_ptr in a map.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're storing it as pointers, you will have to iterate over the map, storing first the key, and then the pointed-to Account, one by one.

This seems like something that could be done better with a database.  Especially if you're going to need to do this in more than one place.

The practice of doing this with objects is known as serialization.

If your Account class is what's known as a plain old data class (i.e. it contains no pointers and no classes or structs apart from other plain old data classes and structs) you can simply write its memory directly to a file.  In that case, an approach like the following would be acceptable:

```
int32_t sizeAccount = sizeof(Account); // this should always be a 32 bit int
for (map<string, Account *>::iterator i = accounts.begin(); i != accounts.end(); ++i)
{
    int32_t sizeStr = i->first.length() + 1; // this should always be a 32 bit int

    os.write(&sizeStr, sizeof(sizeStr)); // 4 byte length of string
    os.write(i->first.c_str(), sizeStr); // null terminated string

    os.write(&sizeAccount, sizeof(sizeAccount)); // 4 byte size of object
    os.write(i->second, sizeAccount);    // object data itself
}
```

If, however, your object has any pointer members, or any members of a type that have pointer members, or any subclasses or superclasses, or any members of types that have subclasses or superclasses, etc, this approach may not be sufficient and may yield either nonsensical or plain incorrect output.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is also known as [Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

[Check this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/201372/saving-stl-maps-to-file-as-binarypossible) thread in another forum, it may help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to output them one by one.

Binary writes do not work correctly on any class which (internally) contains a pointer. That certainly include std::map, std::string etc.

Comment: acounts[0] is not legal because 0 is not a string. You need to use iterators and the begin and end methods.

Comment: im not following ? if i do os.write(*put something here*)

Comment: Well yes you need to 'put something here'. Unfortunately no-one can tell what you need to put there without seeing your definition of `Account`.

Comment: class Account {
public:
    Account();
    ~Account();
    Account(int,int,string,string,int,string,double);
    
    //Extraction Operator >>
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Account& accObj);
    //Insertion Operator <<
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Account* accObj);

private:
    int BSB;
    int Acc;
    string Name;
    string Address;
    int phone;
    string openDate;
    double balance;
};

Comment: OK, well see each of those data members (BSB, Acc, Name etc), each one of those will have to be output with a separate os.write() statement. In fact the strings will probably need two os.write() statements. One for the length and one for the characters. Remember there is no one answer for binary file formats. You have to *design* the format. And what the correct answer is depends on how you design the file format.

Comment: Thanks for that. i really appreciate it ill see how i go

Comment: so how can i do that with an iterator? if .second is all my values ?