# TXT or CSV to C++ Map

Tags: c++, csv, text, dictionary

I'm looking for the best/simplest way to take data from a txt file I have and incorporate that data into a map container in C++.  I have a two-dimensional txt file with all unsigned integers integers.  I could also reformat the file as a CSV if that would be easier.

Here is the code where I try to import data and then print it out.
Code snippet:

```
 static const int rowamount = 13;

// Store pairs (Time, LeapSeconds)
map<int, int> result;

// Read data from file
ifstream input("Test.txt");
for (int currrow = 1; currrow <= rowamount; currrow++)
{
    int timekey;
    input >> timekey;

    int LeapSecondField;
    input >> LeapSecondField;

    // Store in the map
    result[timekey] = LeapSecondField;
}

for (auto it = result.begin(); it != result.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << it->first  << endl;
    cout << it->second << endl;
}
```

The file:

```
173059200 23
252028800 24
315187200 25
346723200 26
393984000 27
425520000 28
457056000 29
504489600 30
551750400 31
599184000 32
820108800 33
914803200 34
1025136000 35
```

My output is like:

```
1606663856
32767
```

I'm not sure why it would be doing this.

Comment: Are you sure you're using correct input file ?

Comment: Yes I am.  In this program I create a file on my desktop named LeapList.txt and then I access the same file.

Comment: Can you check `std::cout<<input.good()<<std::endl;` , before for loop ?

Comment: Your code works just fine when I compile it and run it against a text file with the exakt content you specify. However you should always check that your read operation was successful before using any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd use `istream_iterator` to handle most of the work, so the result would look something like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

// Technically these aren't allowed, but they work fine with every 
// real compiler of which I'm aware.
namespace std {
    std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, std::pair<int, int> &p) {
        return is >> p.first >> p.second;
    }

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, std::pair<int, int> const &p) {
        return os << p.first << "\t" << p.second;
    }
}

int main(){ 
    std::ifstream in("test.txt");

    std::map<int, int> data{std::istream_iterator<std::pair<int, int>>(in),
                std::istream_iterator<std::pair<int, int>>()};

    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator < std::pair<int, int>>(std::cout, "\n"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking that the read operations were successful before using the data read.

If the `>>` operator (in your case for `std::basic_ifstream`) call fails, then the value is left *unmodified* and the program continues. If that value was not previously initialized then reading it after such a failure will result in undefined behaviour.

To check if a read operation was successful simply check the return type from the `>>` operator:

```
if (input_stream >> value) {
    std::cout << "Successfully read value: " << value;
} else {
    std::cout << "Failed to read value.";
}
```

Here's a simple solution to how you can safely read the data from the text file into your map (the tokens in the text file must be separated by whitespace).

```
std::ifstream input("Test.txt");
std::map<int, int> m;
for (int token1, token2; input >> token1 >> token2;) {
    m[token1] = token2;
}
```

**Live example:** http://ideone.com/oLG4HN

Answer (score 0):

You could also open the file in binary using the ios::bin flag, this way you can directly input/output values into/from your map.

Comment: Here is a source: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/284533-working-binary-files-c

Or:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935078/output-a-stdmap-to-a-binary-file